# dimension of vector space on complex field C

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

[image]

By the theorem " if $W$ is a finite dimensional vector space $V(F)$, then $W$ is finite dimensional and $\dim W \leq \dim V$. Also $\dim W=\dim V \Leftrightarrow W=V.$

Here dimension of $M_{10}(\mathbb C)$ is $10 \times 10=100.$ So answer should be (3).... am I right or wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that the dimension of $M_{10}(\mathbb{C})$ is $100$. Yet the subspace you consider might well have a smaller dimesion as you do not know if it equals the full space.

To answer the question correctly recall the [Theorem of Cayley and Hamilton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem).

There you can see that $P(A)=0$ for $P$ the characteristic polynomial of $A$, a polynomial of degree $10$. This means $A^{10} = -a_0I - \dots - a_9A^9$. From this it follows that you can write every $A^n$ as a combination of $I, A, \dots, A^9$. Whence the dimension is at most $10$.

Comment: @ quid  dimension of subspace $< 100$ so answer will be option 3

Comment: Note that 3 also asserts that the dimension is greater than $10$. How would you show that it is greater than $10$?

Comment: @ quid  what is the answer of the question...

Comment: Did you try to have a look at the link I gave you? I upated the post.